# angular inject error. NulInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule) [CartPage -> TabsPage]

Tags: angular

The following code

```
constructor (
   *private tab: TabsPage,*  //here is NulInjectorError
   private router: Router,
) {
 ////E.G. 
//if( TabsPage != NULL) {    
//   inject
//} else {
 //  ...
 //}
}
```

> Can you inject dynamically?
>   Would it be all right?
>   What should be done?

Comment: Are your 2 pages are on the same module?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can inject dynamically. Try this:-

```
     tabInstance: Tabspage;
      constructor(private injector: Injector){} // create instance of injector
      someMethod(){
         this.tabInstance = this.injector.get(TabsPage); // you can get the instance of TabsPage in whichever method it's required
       }
```